# Darkmode automatically enabled on Android in Ionic-Vue App

Tags: android, vue.js, ionic-framework, darkmode, ionic-vue

We are developing an Ionic-Vue App for both Android and iOS. In Chrome dev tools the app is behaving as expected: Darkmode is disabled by default and enabled when switching to "prefers-color-scheme: dark". However, when testing the app on real android devices, darkmode is sometimes enabled even though the user is not running the device in darkmode.

Here is our package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.0",
    "@capacitor/android": "^3.0.0-rc.4",
    "@capacitor/app": "1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.0.0-rc.4",
    "@capacitor/device": "^1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^3.3.3",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.0.2",
    "@capacitor/push-notifications": "^1.0.3",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.35.0",
    "@ionic-native/fingerprint-aio": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/globalization": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.35.0",
    "@ionic/cli": "^6.18.1",
    "@ionic/vue": "6",
    "@ionic/vue-router": "6",
    "@types/npm": "^7.19.0",
    "apexcharts": "^3.27.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio": "^4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-globalization": "^1.11.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "vue": "^3.2.31",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.1.7",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.12",
    "vue3-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-rc.2",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"},
"devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.19",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0-rc.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress": "~5.0.0-rc.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0-rc.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0-rc.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0-rc.3",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0-rc.3",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
    "cypress": "^8.3.0",
    "jest": "^27.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.35.2",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.0",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.4",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0"
  }
```

This is our variables.css configuring the color themes:

```
:root {
--ion-color-primary: #0d6efd;
--ion-color-primary-rgb: 13,110,253;
--ion-color-primary-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-primary-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
--ion-color-primary-shade: #0b61df;
--ion-color-primary-tint: #257dfd;

  --ion-color-secondary: #cfe2ff;
--ion-color-secondary-rgb: 207,226,255;
--ion-color-secondary-contrast: #000000;
--ion-color-secondary-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
--ion-color-secondary-shade: #b6c7e0;
--ion-color-secondary-tint: #d4e5ff;

--ion-color-tertiary: #6610f2;
--ion-color-tertiary-rgb: 102,16,242;
--ion-color-tertiary-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-tertiary-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
--ion-color-tertiary-shade: #5a0ed5;
--ion-color-tertiary-tint: #7528f3;

--ion-color-success: #198754;
--ion-color-success-rgb: 25,135,84;
--ion-color-success-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-success-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
--ion-color-success-shade: #16774a;
--ion-color-success-tint: #309365;

--ion-color-warning: #ffc107;
--ion-color-warning-rgb: 255,193,7;
--ion-color-warning-contrast: #000000;
--ion-color-warning-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
--ion-color-warning-shade: #e0aa06;
--ion-color-warning-tint: #ffc720;

--ion-color-danger: #dc3545;
--ion-color-danger-rgb: 220,53,69;
--ion-color-danger-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-danger-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
--ion-color-danger-shade: #c22f3d;
--ion-color-danger-tint: #e04958;

--ion-color-medium: #92949c;
--ion-color-medium-rgb: 146,148,156;
--ion-color-medium-contrast: #000000;
--ion-color-medium-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
--ion-color-medium-shade: #808289;
--ion-color-medium-tint: #9d9fa6;

--ion-color-light: #f4f5f8;
--ion-color-light-rgb: 244,245,248;
--ion-color-light-contrast: #000000;
--ion-color-light-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
--ion-color-light-shade: #d7d8da;
--ion-color-light-tint: #f5f6f9;

}


ion-toolbar {
    --color: var(--ion-color-primary);
}

ion-list-header{
    --color: var(--ion-color-primary);
}

ion-fab-button {
    --color: var(--ion-color-primary);
    --background: var(--ion-color-primary-contrast);
    --background-activated: : var(--ion-color-secondary);
}

ion-item-divider{
    --background: var(--ion-color-light-tint);
    --color: var(--ion-color-light-contrast);
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
/*
 * Dark Colors
 * -------------------------------------------
 */
/** Ionic CSS Variables **/
:root {

--ion-color-primary: #084298;
--ion-color-primary-rgb: 66,140,255;
--ion-color-primary-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-primary-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
--ion-color-primary-shade: #3a7be0;
--ion-color-primary-tint: #5598ff;

--ion-color-secondary: #084298;
--ion-color-secondary-rgb: 66,140,255;
--ion-color-secondary-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-secondary-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
--ion-color-secondary-shade: #3a7be0;
--ion-color-secondary-tint: #5598ff;

--ion-color-tertiary: #6a64ff;
--ion-color-tertiary-rgb: 106,100,255;
--ion-color-tertiary-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-tertiary-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
--ion-color-tertiary-shade: #5d58e0;
--ion-color-tertiary-tint: #7974ff;

--ion-color-success: #198754;
--ion-color-success-rgb: 25,135,84;
--ion-color-success-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-success-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
--ion-color-success-shade: #16774a;
--ion-color-success-tint: #309365;

--ion-color-warning: #ffc107;
--ion-color-warning-rgb: 255,193,7;
--ion-color-warning-contrast: #000000;
--ion-color-warning-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
--ion-color-warning-shade: #e0aa06;
--ion-color-warning-tint: #ffc720;

--ion-color-danger: #dc3545;
--ion-color-danger-rgb: 220,53,69;
--ion-color-danger-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-danger-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
--ion-color-danger-shade: #c22f3d;
--ion-color-danger-tint: #e04958;

--ion-color-dark: #f4f5f8;
--ion-color-dark-rgb: 244,245,248;
--ion-color-dark-contrast: #000000;
--ion-color-dark-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
--ion-color-dark-shade: #d7d8da;
--ion-color-dark-tint: #f5f6f9;

--ion-color-medium: #989aa2;
--ion-color-medium-rgb: 152,154,162;
--ion-color-medium-contrast: #000000;
--ion-color-medium-contrast-rgb: 0,0,0;
--ion-color-medium-shade: #86888f;
--ion-color-medium-tint: #a2a4ab;

--ion-color-light: #222428;
--ion-color-light-rgb: 34,36,40;
--ion-color-light-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-light-contrast-rgb: 255,255,255;
--ion-color-light-shade: #1e2023;
--ion-color-light-tint: #383a3e;
  }

ion-toolbar {
    --background: var(--ion-color-primary);
    --color: var(--ion-color-primary-contrast);
}

ion-list-header{
    --background: var(--ion-color-dark-contrast);
    --color: var(--ion-color-primary-contrast);
}

ion-fab-button {
    --background: var(--ion-color-primary);
    --color: var(--ion-color-primary-contrast);
}

  /*
   * iOS Dark Theme
   * -------------------------------------------
   */

  .ios body {

--ion-background-color: #000000;
--ion-background-color-rgb: 0,0,0;

--ion-text-color: #ffffff;
--ion-text-color-rgb: 255,255,255;

--ion-color-step-50: #0d0d0d;
--ion-color-step-100: #1a1a1a;
--ion-color-step-150: #262626;
--ion-color-step-200: #333333;
--ion-color-step-250: #404040;
--ion-color-step-300: #4d4d4d;
--ion-color-step-350: #595959;
--ion-color-step-400: #666666;
--ion-color-step-450: #737373;
--ion-color-step-500: #808080;
--ion-color-step-550: #8c8c8c;
--ion-color-step-600: #999999;
--ion-color-step-650: #a6a6a6;
--ion-color-step-700: #b3b3b3;
--ion-color-step-750: #bfbfbf;
--ion-color-step-800: #cccccc;
--ion-color-step-850: #d9d9d9;
--ion-color-step-900: #e6e6e6;
--ion-color-step-950: #f2f2f2;

--ion-toolbar-background: #0d0d0d;

--ion-item-background: #1c1c1c;
--ion-item-background-activated: #313131;
  }


  /*
   * Material Design Dark Theme
   * -------------------------------------------
   */

  .md body {
--ion-background-color: #121212;
--ion-background-color-rgb: 18,18,18;

--ion-text-color: #ffffff;
--ion-text-color-rgb: 255,255,255;

--ion-border-color: #222222;

--ion-color-step-50: #1e1e1e;
--ion-color-step-100: #2a2a2a;
--ion-color-step-150: #363636;
--ion-color-step-200: #414141;
--ion-color-step-250: #4d4d4d;
--ion-color-step-300: #595959;
--ion-color-step-350: #656565;
--ion-color-step-400: #717171;
--ion-color-step-450: #7d7d7d;
--ion-color-step-500: #898989;
--ion-color-step-550: #949494;
--ion-color-step-600: #a0a0a0;
--ion-color-step-650: #acacac;
--ion-color-step-700: #b8b8b8;
--ion-color-step-750: #c4c4c4;
--ion-color-step-800: #d0d0d0;
--ion-color-step-850: #dbdbdb;
--ion-color-step-900: #e7e7e7;
--ion-color-step-950: #f3f3f3;

--ion-item-background: #1A1B1E;
  }

  ion-title.title-large {
    --color: white;
  }

}
```

The bug does not (seem to) occur in iOS and it did not (seem to) occur before moving to Ionic 6. We did not override any android specific configurations. Any help is appreciated.